# Delete Google Sheets columns based on column name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet from a system export.  I want to delete certain columns based on name.  The columns are not alongside each other.

To delete all together, I will want to getRange where the range variable have specific header names.

I am running into a problem of figuring out how to define a range and then delete it.

EDIT:  I cannot use the standard deleteColumn method, as the order of columns differs day by day.

```
function deleteColumns() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('data'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  var header = spreadsheet.getRange('1:1');
  var deleteValues = (header.getValues());
 var counter = 1;

  for (i=0; i<header.length; i++) {
     if
        (
        ( deleteValues[i] == 'example A') ||
        ( deleteValues[i] == 'example B') ||
        ( deleteValues[i] == 'example C') ||
        ( deleteValues[i] == 'example D') ||
        ( deleteValues[i] == 'example E')
        )
        {
          spreadsheet.deleteColumn(counter); }
    else {
      var counter = counter + 1;
    }
        }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete a column using method **deleteColumn(*column_position*)**:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
// Columns start at "1" - this deletes the first column
sheet.deleteColumn(1);
```

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deletecolumncolumnposition

In your situation, an approach, should be get the range of row where there are name of the columns and with for loop and a counter (which starts at 1 and which increases by 1 for each check). So if the value of the cell is the same one you defined, the index of the column is the value of counter.
I.E.:

```
counter = 1;
for (i=0; i<range.length; i++) {
    if (deleteValues[i] == 'exampleA' ||
       deleteValues[i] == 'exampleB' ||
       deleteValues[i] == 'exampleC' ||
       deleteValues[i] == 'exampleD') {
           sheet.deleteColumn(counter);
    } else {
       counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: in addition to some conceptual issues your code had to be modified in other places in order to work. Here is the working code:

```
function deleteColumns() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Foglio2'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('1:1').activate();
  var header = spreadsheet.getRange('1:1');
  var deleteValues = (header.getValues());
  var counter = 1;

  for (i=0; i<deleteValues[0].length; i++) {
    if
      (
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'exampleA' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'exampleB' ||
         deleteValues[0][i] == 'exampleC' ||
           deleteValues[0][i] == 'exampleD'
          )
          {
            spreadsheet.deleteColumn(counter); }
    else {
      counter = counter + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to start at the end and work down, if you start at 0 you'll skip columns each time you delete one. But other wise this.

Comment: @J.G. I adapted the code to work from index 0. Thank for observation.

Comment: @MichelePisani I am still a bit confused.  The function runs but does not delete any columns.  I updated my code in the original question

Comment: Because with getRange('1:1') your are taking only the first row and the first column https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column

Comment: I set it to the entire sheet and still not working.  It also drastically slows it down.  I _only_ want to search row 1 for the values.  If row 1 has the values, then it should delete the corresponding column.

Comment: I modified my post by adding the complete and working code, if you look at the for loop you can see that some conceptual issues in your code had to be fixed.

Comment: @MichelePisani you made my date.  Thank you for your help!